cx_freeze error: Executable.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'shortcutName'
When I try to compile a .py file with cx_freeze I get an error like this:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\gonza\OneDrive\Escritorio\omfg\setup.py", line 9, in <module>
    Executable(r"C:\Users\gonza\OneDrive\Escritorio\Auto Whattsapp\autowhatts.py",
TypeError: Executable.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'shortcutName'

I don't know why this is happening, because I have the shortcutName argument as it should be (I think)
Here's my code, I hope I can find a solution:
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
    name="Auto Whattsapp Messages",
    version="1.0",
    author="None",
    description="Send Whattsapp messages automatically",
    executables = [
    Executable(r"C:\Users\gonza\OneDrive\Escritorio\Auto Whattsapp\autowhatts.py",
            icon=r"C:\Users\gonza\OneDrive\Escritorio\Auto Whattsapp\whatsapp.ico",
            shortcutName = "Auto Whattsapp",
            shortcutDir = "Auto Whattsapp")
        ]
    )

btw those 'r' are for preventing a syntax error (I think so)
I tried changing the argument name, but it didn't work, I don't think changing the argument name would do anything, please help!

I never used this library before but it seems that the parameter you are looking for is called shortcut_name and not shortcutName. (The same is the case for  shortcutDir which should be shortcut_dir)
For reference
https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/stable/setup_script.html#cx-freeze-executable
